# xpath where && clause

Tags: xpath, xquery, sedna

I have xml data like this

```
<users>
    <user email="email@email.com">
        <password>pass</password>
        ..
    </user>
</users>
```

I want to retrieve the **user's record (xml format)** filtering by email and password. 
I have tried

```
for $user in doc("users")/user
               [@email="'.$email.'"]
               [password="'.$password.'"] 
return $user
```

but I get errors.

Please, how can I retrieve that **user's data in xml format** so that I can use something like domdocument or simplexmlparser to get the respective nodes?

My reference was http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: if i use for $user in doc("users")/user[@email="'.$email.'"] return $user, it works but returns data as string and not xml and it also validates only by email and not password.

Comment: "i get errors" is no reasonable problem statement. Please post the _exact_ error message or wrong data that is printed.

Comment: And furthermore -- it seems like you put together XQuery expressions in PHP? Injection attacks are also possible in XQuery if queries are constructed like this. The same applies as in SQL: always use predefined statements, and register external variables for parameters to be injection-safe.

Comment: Also note that `for $x in Z return $x` is just a long-winded way of writing `Z`.

Comment: thanks @MichaelKay. Please, that returns just an array of strings. Is there something that i should do to return the xml format of user? what i have now is **doc("users")//user')** and it returns an array of string.

Comment: I just noticed that inside each element in the array, is the xml data and used domdocument to parse the data. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Your expression returns a sequence of element nodes, not an array of strings. What happens to that sequence of element nodes depends on your calling application and the rules of its XPath API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably want to combine the constrains to one single constraint

```
for $user in doc("users")//user[@email="'.$email.'" and password="'.$password.'"] return $user
```

This could also be achieved in one go by:

```
doc("users")//user[@email="'.$email.'" and password="'.$password.'"]
```

HTH,

Peter

Comment: thanks @prker, i updated my code with your answer now have no error but it does not pull anything from the database.

Comment: Your answer doesn't really answer the question nor does it actually improve anything. Having multiple predicated is actually the same thing as concatenating them with `and`. This is just a matter of style.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of the errors you report is that your query asked for `user` elements that appear as the outermost element of the `users` document and which satisfy some further constraints, thus:

```
doc("users")/user[...][...]
```

But the XML you show has `users`, not `user`, as the outermost element.

In the short run, using `...//user` instead of `.../user`, as is done in prker's answer, will solve this problem.  (His recommendation to use only a single predicate makes no sense and has nothing to do with whatever problems you had.)  The problem can also be fixed by getting the path right:  `doc("users")/users/user...`

In the long run, you should learn to understand what is happening in your XPath expressions. Here, `doc("users")` returns the document node at the root of the XML document you specify, and the next step, `/user` (short for `/child::user`) asks for an element node named `user` which is the child of the document node.

Answer (score -1):

It worked with this

```
'for $user in doc("users")//user 
  where 
    $user/password = "'.$password.'" and 
    $user[@email="'.$email.'"] 
  return $user ';
```

Reference from http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xquery_intro.asp

Comment: I have to downvote your answer, because it is not at all useful. The statement your wrote is the exact same thing as in your question, just more verbose. The only difference is that this time you used `//user` (the descendant-and-self selector) and before you used `/user`, i.e. just the child selector. Most likely your selection for user was simply wrong, e.g. it might have been `/users/user`, depending on your actual data.

Comment: Also, if this works the answer by @prker will also works. If it does not, your processor is broken or you are doing something else wrong which we can not see with the provided information.

Comment: ok  @prker's answer works just that i had some wrong index in storing data in the db.